# Class Methods Only Included Once When Using Concerns in Rails 3 with Namespaced Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activesupport-concern

I have a folder structure that looks like the following:

```
app/models/
    concerns/
        quxable.rb
    foo/
        bar.rb
        baz.rb
```

I'm in Rails 3 so I've autoloaded my concerns with:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', "concerns", '**/')]
```

And the files are as follows:

**quxable.rb**

```
module Quxable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern        

    module ClassMethods
        def new_method
        end
    end
end
```

**bar.rb**

```
class Foo::Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Quxable
end
```

**baz.rb**

```
class Foo::Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Quxable
end
```

Now in the console if do this, I get the following outputs:

```
Foo::Bar.respond_to? :new_method #=> true
Foo::Baz.respond_to? :new_method #=> false
reload!
Foo::Baz.respond_to? :new_method #=> true
Foo::Bar.respond_to? :new_method #=> false
```

So it would seem to only be properly included on the model that is first accessed. And yet, If I run the following:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.select{ |c| c.included_modules.include?(Quxable) }.map(&:name)
```

I get `["Foo::Bar", "Foo::Baz"]`.

Any idea what's going on here? I'm guessing something with autoloading/eagerloading, but I'm not sure why both models aren't getting the new class method.

PS - I've tried rewriting the module without `ActiveSupport::Concern` (just because I'm on an old Rails version and I'm taking shots in the dark) using:

```
def include(base)
    base.send :extend, ClassMethods
end
```

but I still have the same problem.

**EDIT**

I initially left this out (just trying to present the simplest problem), so I apologize to those trying to help earlier. But `quxable.rb` actually looks like this:

```
module Quxable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern 

    LOOKUP = {
        Foo::Bar => "something",
        Foo::Baz => "something else"
    }

    module ClassMethods
        def new_method
        end
    end
end
```

So I'm guessing I created some kind of circular dependency defining a constant with the Class objects. Can anyone confirm? Weird that it just fails silently by not defining the class methods on the class that's accessed second though. I don't know why that is?

Comment: Do your classes have .rb at the end of their names?

Comment: No, typo. I'll fix it.

Comment: I've just created dummy application with a code you submit, cannot reproduce the issue. Any chance you could show your actual module and classes?

Comment: Sorry I can't. I will say I left out one complexity in that `Foo::Bar` and `Foo::Baz` actually extend a different base class that opens a connection to a third party database as described here: http://ilikestuffblog.com/2012/09/21/establishing-a-connection-to-a-non-default-database-in-rails-3-2-2/ But that base class doesn't include the mixin or do anything special other than connect to an external database.

Comment: That lookup is problematic. It will instantiate Foo::Bar before the module is complete. Thus new_method will be omitted. Tradition in this case is to use strings in the lookup and .constantize them to turn them into classes when needed.

Comment: But I suggest you use the class, module and folder structure I describe in my answer, as it requires no changes to Rails configuration and thus won't bite you in the ass later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your edit, this code is problematic:

```
LOOKUP = {
    Foo::Bar => "something",
    Foo::Baz => "something else"
}
```

It will instantiate Foo::Bar before the module is complete. Thus `new_method` will be omitted. Tradition in this case is to use strings in the lookup and .constantize them to turn them into classes when needed.

```
LOOKUP = {
    "Foo::Bar" => "something",
    "Foo::Baz" => "something else"
}
```

then

```
LOOKUP.keys.first.constantize.new_method
```

or

```
result = LOOKUP[Foo::Bar.name]
```

to use it.

Comment: That's what I wound up doing. Thanks for working it from all the possible angles lol!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo, and concerns include some magic that lets you transcend the limitations on mix-ins.

Also, if you're working in a directory under something that's already autoloaded, like 'models', just namespace everything to that directory name.

Try this:

```
module Concerns
  module Quxable

    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      def self.new_method
      end
    end
  end
end


module Foo
  class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Concerns::Quxable
  end
end
```

As far as I remember you shouldn't need the extra autoload directive, as using the namespace in a directory under models will just work.

---

Edit after comments:

I've set up a Rails project with the following added files:

app/models/foo/doer.rb

app/models/foo/thinker.rb

app/models/concerns/thingable.rb

thingable.rb is:

```
module Concerns
  module Thingable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    included do
      def self.thing
      end
    end
  end
end
```

doer.rb is:

```
module Foo
  class Doer < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Concerns::Thingable
  end
end
```

thinker.rb is:

```
module Foo
  class Thinker < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Concerns::Thingable
  end
end
```

In a console:

Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.22)

2.1.3 :001 > Foo::Doer.respond_to? :thing

=> true

2.1.3 :002 > Foo::Thinker.respond_to? :thing

=> true

2.1.3 :003 > reload!

Reloading...

=> true

2.1.3 :004 > Foo::Doer.respond_to? :thing

=> true

2.1.3 :005 > Foo::Thinker.respond_to? :thing

=> true

2.1.3 :006 >

I did not change the autoloading at all, I relied on Rails to find files based on namespacing. (Use a namespace for directories under known directories like 'models')

I would reset your autoloading to default, then use Rails conventions for file locations and namespacing. If that doesn't work, there may be other things your project is doing that I don't know about.

Let me know if you can provide any more details.

Comment: I don't think I should need `module Concerns`. Examples don't do that. Also you can use `module ClassMethods...` to define a class method with Concerns. Plus I tried skipping the `ActiveSupport::Concern` mixin--same problem. And I'm pretty sure my autoloading setup is correct in the sense that my models and concerns load. But something is off in that only the first model accessed receives the class method, even though both include the Concern.

Comment: In my experience, defining modules and classes on the same line using :: syntax can lead to errors down the line. It's best to define them on separate lines.

Comment: I'm currently using concerns extensively on a project using the 'concerns' namespace and it works great. Rails convention is that if you use a folder under an autoloaded folder like 'models' or 'controllers' then Rails knows to look there because of namespaces.

Comment: tl;dr: did you try my suggestion or just pick holes? ;)

Comment: I have a feeling your autoloading setup may be conflicting Rails, hence the issues. Seems to me that you're telling it to go against convention, which will cause much pain in Rails land.

Comment: No dice, defining both the concern and the classes expressly within the module and turning off autoloading. But I don't know that using autoloading is against Rails conventions. Autloading `app/models/concerns` is default behavior in Rails 4, I just did it myself because I'm on 3.

Comment: "Also you can use module ClassMethods... to define a class method with Concerns" - Yes you can. However, I prefer using the same syntax that you use in a class, allowing faster refactoring and fewer refactoring errors when cutting and pasting code. :)

Comment: I didn't even know Rails 3 supported Concerns. You could try, instead, using https://github.com/chemica/augmentations-gem and see if it works better?

Comment: As an aside, if I get a moment I'll try recreating your problem in Rails3 and see what happens...

Comment: Yeah they do, just not as "out-the-box" as Rails 4. But I tried just making it a normal mixin without using any of the `ActiveSupport::Concern` conveniences, same problems. But cool, thanks for trying!

Comment: Updated answer based on testing using Rails 3

Comment: Updated to reflect more than one model

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97667/discussion-between-gray-kemmey-and-a-fader-darkly).